# Cancel Heroku payment after creating the app

Tags: heroku

I recently employed some apps on Heroku. I have finished using them so I want to cancel the payment of these apps on Heroku. Could somebody please tell me what to do if I still want to use Heroku in the future?

I haven't actually tried anything because I don't know what to do exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to close the account:

1. Login to Heroku
2. Remove (delete) all your apps and pay your dues
3. Go to your profile (top-right) - Account Settings
4. Select "Close this account" and enter your password.